# Application starts on different port than what is in launchSettings

Tags: asp.net-core, localhost, port

So, I changed the ports in the launchSettings.json to this:

```
"MyProject": {
    "commandName": "Project",
    "launchBrowser": true,
    "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5005;http://localhost:5004",
    "environmentVariables": {
      "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
    }
}
```

I even tried adding this:

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
        {
            webBuilder.UseUrls("https://localhost:5005","http://localhost:5004");
            webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
        });
```

I searched the entire application for "5000" and no results are returned.  Yet, every time I start the application, it goes to port 5000.  (Which I want to be used by a different application.)

[image: Image of console showing app is utilizing port 5000]

Comment: Pretty sure it runs on the port specified under "iisSettings" in launchSettings.json

Comment: 5000 isn't anywhere in the entire project or solution for that matter.

Comment: Have you tried using Kestrel config?
```"Kestrel": {
    "Endpoints": {
      "Http": {
        "Url": "http://0.0.0.0:6000"
      }
    }
  }```

Comment: Same thing happening to me